# Changing a document in the root domain folder

Tags: domains, document-root

I am a relatively new web developer/marketing manager for an e-commerce website set-up using prestashop (theoutdoorappliancestore.com).

To start off they had hired an outside guy that created a landing page for SEO optimization. The problem is that the landing page has a completely seperate look & feel from the shop, and you need to follow a link from this page to get to the e-commerce site.

theoutdoorappliancestore.com - SEO landing page

theoutdoorappliancestore.com/shop - e-commerce store

My plan is to get rid of the landing page all together and use the Prestashop homepage as the true homepage instead of theoutdoorappliancestore.com/shop

All I need to do is move the current page theoutdoorappliancestore.com/shop to theoutdoorappliancestore.com and I need some direction.

My question is would I have to do anything other than delete/rearrange the files in the cPanel file manager?

Comment: Apart from _deleting_ the original landing page. I imagine this is probably something you'll need to manage within Prestashop. ie. Change the URL of Prestashop's homepage from `/shop` to `/`. Alternatively you could simply implement a redirect from `/` to `/shop` in .htaccess and `/shop` will become your new homepage.

Comment: I am a firm believer that it is better to make software use the / directory if you can and reserving any redirect or a URL rewrite as a second option. I do not know Prestashop so I cannot tell you how to do this. However, if it is at all possible, it is probably better to see what options there are in the configuration first. Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I am trying to avoid redirection if possible. So if I delete the landing page and related pages that aren't part of the e-commerce shop, then change the base URL on prestashop from /shop/ to / I should be all set? Sorry I just want to make sure I understand everything before attempting to make the changes.

Comment: I do not know Prestashop at all. If you can change the URL from /shop to / in the configuration, then that sounds good to me. One warning however, I would not delete any files, but rather, rename them just in case. Cheers!!